Converting Word Document to PDF with Winnovative - Form Fields
I have a word document, that I want to convert to PDF via Winnovative. The basics work, as done with the following function.
public byte[] ConvertWordToPdf(Stream fileStream)
{
    var wordToPdfConverter = new WnvWordToPdf.WordToPdfConverter();
    wordToPdfConverter.LicenseKey = "InsertKeyHere";

    var pdfDocument = wordToPdfConverter.ConvertWordStreamToPdfDocumentObject(fileStream);

    return pdfDocument.Save();
}

My current problem: I want to have a form field in the resulting PDF file. Just some simple text boxes. I tried adding fields to the word file via the following methods:

developer tools -> content controls -> plain text content control
developer tools -> content controls -> legacy form text control

After converting the word file to PDF, those controls didn't stay as form fields.
=> Question: Which options do I need to use to actually generate form fields in the final output? I couldn't find any information on how to do this.
